# How to add Pure CSS Parallax Scrolling

Tags: html, css, parallax

I would like to add some pure CSS parallax scrolling functionality to my website, but everything I've tried doesn't seem to work. I've searched here for answers too, but nothing answers my question. Does anybody know how I can take this code: http://wolfleader116.github.io/
(Sorry, the Doctype declaration isn't indented like that in the actual file.)
and add a pure CSS parallax scrolling feature so that the background scrolls at half speed? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you have tried so far so people can help you wherever you have found a roadblock

Comment: Um... All the code is at http://wolfleader116.github.io/

Comment: You should try to do this at least, put up a test page somewhere, or try recreate it in jsfiddle, or codepen. Then link to that...

Comment: @Josh And if that link dies, then it becomes useless and this question still won't have any code. Help us help you :-) Include the minimal code necessary for recreating your scenario in your question; that's how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I gave you all the source code.... Do you mean what the page actually looks like? Because I don't see how that will help very much, but it's at http://wolfleader116.github.io/Example.html

Comment: @Josh, StackOverflow is designed to be future-proof. This means we want people with the same problem as yours to profit from your question. If your link breaks, this will not happen. Please paste the relevant code **directly in the question.**

Comment: @TiagoMarinho I wasn't able to do that as the question would be WAY too long for anybody to want to read. That was the issue with pasting directly into the question. I'm not sure anybody wants to scroll through 150-200 lines of code... Never mind I never saw that you said minimal sorry.

Comment: That's why I'm asking you for the relevant part only. We don't want all your code here. And even if the relevant part of the code have lots of lines, we can just ignore it and see your link, if it still active. The code should be correctly formatted in the question so it will automatically have a `max-height` and `overflow-y` and we will not need to scroll all over it to see the answers.

Comment: Never mind about shortening code. The code gets broken by the mini-markdown thing and doesn't show the actual code, but instead shows something entirely different with bullet lists, etc.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. Are you sure you know how to correctly format the code in the question? Paste your code in the question, select it and then click the `{}` icon and it'll be automatically formatted for you.

Answer (score 7):

You Can Try this tutorial. 
[Tutorial Link 1](http://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw)
[Tutorial Link 2](http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/pure-css-parallax-websites/)

```
body { 
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 perspective: 1px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 height: 100%;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 font-family: Nunito;
}
```

Comment: **Someone** understands the meaning of _pure_ js ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `background-attachment: fixed` css style to create a CSS only parallax scroll. This uses the concept of the `background-image` being fixed and the remaining content scrolling with the page.

```
.parallax div{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 50vh;
    text-indent : -9999px;
    position : relative;
    background-position   : center center;
    background-size       : cover;
      &:nth-child( 2n ) {
      box-shadow : inset 0 0 1em #111; 
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vammk2pp/)**

Comment: How do you change the scrolling speed (scrolling offset) of the background image once you have used this method? I've read it has to do with the `transform:` property but I still cannot figure how to adjust the speed using this method (with the code above, the parallax stays completely still while page scrolls above. Instead, I would like the parallax background to scroll at a very slow rate as the user is scrolling up/down, using only CSS).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did my website (WIP) with parralax scrolling (http://www.ideathhead.co.uk):

**HTML:**

Add section tags using the attributes below. (Each section represents a slide)

```
<section name="home" id="home" data-type="background" data-speed="10">
          <p class="buzz-out" id="Welcome"></p>                    
        </section>
```

**CSS:**

This will make sure your background image spans across the whole page, and adjusts it's size for every resolution!

```
#home {
background: url(img/slide1.png) 50% 0 repeat fixed;
min-height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And that is literally it, for the basics of parallax scrolling anyway, if you dig further on the interwebs you could do some playing around for some cooler effects, remember, GOOGLE IS YOUR FRIEND!

**_________________________________________________________________**

## **BELOW IS OPTIONAL IF YOUR WILLING TO USE A BIT OF JS!!**

**_________________________________________________________________**

Also, a tip is that if you want to add buttons later on the scroll **smoothly** to certain pages then add this to a JavaScript file:

**JS:**

This script makes page scrolling smoother, so it doesn't just jump to a part of a page

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Then, in your HTML, in  tags, set the href to the ID of the section to scroll to, and it will do so smoothly too! As an example,
**This is the section:**

```
<section name="home" id="home" data-type="background" data-speed="10">
          <p class="buzz-out" id="Welcome"></p>   
        </section>
```

**And this is the button:**

```
<a href="#home">CLICK</a>
```

Remember, it is the ID not the name, because I got confused at first with that!

I was happy to help :)

Comment: JS isn't Pure CSS at all

Comment: It is optional, just a nice touch I like if you are using a nav bar, and dosn't change the effect either.

Comment: It's WIP; just make sure to test on iPhone. Unusable so far. But WIP so you probably already have that planned.

Comment: @HowToGaming Do you think you can take a look at the code at http://wolfleader116.github.io and see exactly how I'm supposed to add this code? It still didn't work after lots of testing. Thanks! :) Also, here https://github.com/WolfLeader116/Wolfleader116.github.io there are some more files that are just the code. Such as Example.html, JS.js and BP.css
Oh and I'm fine with using JS or jQuery, it's just that I'm better at CSS and HTML than JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: @Josh How I did it personally, is that each slide is literally just a background-image in css, and not individually placed HTML images, and then if you are creating for example a "contact us" page, you click on the slide and it will take you to a seperate page with no <section> tag at all, so it is exactly like a new slide, but on another page.

Answer (score 0):

TRY this page scrolling[codepen](https://codepen.io/asiyaf09/pen/gOEamoo)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/JnWFTCM/vadim-kaipov-6k-I0qhmxc4-unsplash.jpgimg_parallax.jpg");

  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 500px; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.</p>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">
Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>

</body>
</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/JnWFTCM/vadim-kaipov-6k-I0qhmxc4-unsplash.jpgimg_parallax.jpg");

  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 500px; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.</p>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">
Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```